# What is an orthogonal point transformation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, terminology, coordinate-systems, definition

It is regarding classical mechanics. I know that a point transformation is the transformation of generalized coordinates. But what is meant by "orthogonal" point transformations?

Comment: Hi @Yaman Sanghavi: Is this taken from a reference? Which page?

Comment: The meaning is going to be a continuous transformation $T$ acting on "position vectors" $x$ giving $T(x)$, such that $T(x)\cdot T(y)=x\cdot y$ with the euclidean scalar product. That is to say: The transformation is linear and its representing matrix is orthogonal. These are rotations around a fixed axis, perhaps together with a reflection.

Comment: @Qmechanic I read this term in Goldstein's Classical Mechanics but didn't find an explanation.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a point transformation which is orthogonal? That is, a transformation $\mathbb Q\rightarrow\mathbb Q$, realized by orthogonal matrices, where $\mathbb Q$ is the configuration space.

Comment: @Diracology Yeah, I think you and Adomas Baliuka are right. Thanks.